# Is there a maximum length for HTML5 input?

Tags: html, base64

I have an HTML text input to store the base64 string from an image canvas.

Apparently when I tried sending a long base64 string to the server, part of the string is not sent which results in grayed out image.

Comment: You are more likely to be hitting a POST/GET limit on the server/browser.  What method are you using and how big is the data?

Comment: I am doing image compression on the client side using Canvas API. I tried uploading an image of size 5MB and it will be compressed to less than .5 MB. The image will then be converted to a base64 string which I will then post using AJAX to the backend (MongoDB). However, when I GET the image and display it on my page, part of the image is greyed out. I assume it's because the base 64 string is partially sent to the server.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18108183/4592572 it might help you. if not try to do it in textarea not flat some times it needs to be in multiple lines. or as  @Alex K. says.